# How to make post stick to its own div

Tags: posts

A Wordpress theme has 4 boxes in front page. Each box has its own posts. please see the screenshot http://prntscr.com/1231qw

I want to let the user edit the post using admin panel and when he save the post then post will again publish to its original box instead of another location which is usually happened.

How can i make a post specific to its div? is there any way?

Any advise please?

Comment: How are the boxed populated?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that gets the actual content of the boxes it's impossible to know for sure. But I guess your problem is that the theme code sorts the posts by modified_date. If you find the line in the code (most likely it will contain get_posts() or WP_Query) you just have to remove the order param (default order is always post_time).